# Вычисление определенного интеграла методом средних прямоугольников с помощью потоков Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

В ргр есть задание написать программу для вычисления определенного интеграла (f(x) = sqrt(2 - x^2) dx) в пределах от 1 до sqrt(2) методом средних прямоугольников, то есть найти суму f(xi + h / 2) * h , 
h = (b - a) / n, xi = a + i*h. И вывести время работи программы.

Проблема состоит в том,что эту тему как-бы для самообучения дали (ознакомительная). А предидущие задания были по полиморфизму, наследованию и интерфейсам. Прочитал в интернете разные статьи. Тема оказалась сложной.

Была попытка написать код, но я сам понимаю, что это полный бред. Но все равно осмелюсь попросить помощи (ведь задание в ргр и очень нужное). 
Поскольку класс не наследуеться от других, использовал наследование от `Thread`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator extends Thread {
int a = 1;
double b = Math.pow(2, 1 / 2);
void threadCalc(threads index, n)
    {
        double h = (b - a) / n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {               
            x [i] = a + i * h;
            double results[i] = (x[i] + h /2)  * h ;
        }
    }
public void run(n) {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];           
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {               
            threads[i] = new Thread(threadCalc);                    
            threads[i].start(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Join();                
        }
        result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            result += results[i];
        }
    }

}
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    System.out.print("Введите кол-во інтервалов: ");
    while (true) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Некорректный тип введенного числа! Повторите попитку: ");
      } else { 
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        return;
    }
}
}
}
```

Знаю прошу многого, но вынуждают обстоятельства.

Comment: я так понимаю,все очень плохо?

Comment: Я правильно понял, основная проблема, это разобраться в работе потоков? А если точнее - посчитать время выполнения отдельным потоком?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim, поймите меня правильно. Я не совсем ориентируюсь в работе потоков по выше указаным причинам. Первая проблема в том, что этот код не работает. В принципе некоторые моменты понятны, например, после пересмотрения ввод кол-ва интервалов scanner - ом надо наверное перенести в конструктор класса  **Calculator**, а потом подкорректировать метод вычисления значения маленького отрезка. Но для написаня конечного кода просто не хватает знаний. А задание выдано вообще не в тему, да и времени в обрез вот и вынужден просить помощи.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim, время работіы программы - вопрос второстепенный, хотя немаловажен.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim, правилами форума  запрещаеться переливать из пустого..., но все равно скажу:  не поймите меня неправильно, и то, что я прошу отредактировать данный код не лень или еще что-то, я не из тех людей,что не попробовав сделать, впадают в панику. Так сложилась данная ситуация. И если Вы согласитесь это сделать, я попрошу Вас объяснить некоторые моменты. Могу  я на Вас рассчитывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что я могу сказать... Да, мой дорогой друг, все очень плохо [image: все очень плохо]

Я причешу сам код, а вот матан сам правь.

```
public class Calculator extends Thread{

    int n;
    int a = 1;
    double b = Math.pow(2, 1 / 2);
    double results[]; 
    //Переменные объявленные в методах не сохраняются в объекте! 
    //Как только закончится работа метода, такая переменная пропадет,    
    //поэтому объявляем все тут.
    public Calculator(int n){
       this.n = n;
    }
    //Если ты создаешь поток переопределяя Thread, ты переопределяешь его метод run, 
    //с которого начинается выполнение потока. Но ты не можешь добавить ему произвольные параметры!
    //Но можно передать индекс через параметры конструктора, что мы и сделали.
    //Так же я вставил сюда расчет чего-то там, раз он должен 
    private void threadCalc(){
        results = new double[n];
        double h = (b - a) / n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {               
            double x = a + i * h;
            results[i] = (x + h /2)  * h ;
        }
    }
   //В параметрах метода все очень строго (тип_переменной имя, тип_переменной имя) а не та билиберда, что ты написал.
   //Раз мы индекс вынесли в тело класса, то я его из параметров убрал
   public double getResult(){
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            result += results[i];
        }
        return result;
   }
   //Чтобы итог из тела потока можно было бы получить, я вынес этот кусок кода в отдельный метод.
   @Override
   public void run() {
        threadCalc();
        Calculator[] threads = new Calculator[n];   
        //Мы переопределили класс Thread, поэтому нам нужен именно калькулятор а не оригинал.        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {               
            threads[i] = new Calculator(i);                    
            threads[i].start();
            //возвращаясь к  параметрам, это тебе не js или питон, ты не можешь передавать метод как объект, 
            //Если тебе его надо выполнять в начале потока, то я поставил запуск метода в самом начале метода.
            //Как я говорил, в самом матане я не разберался, и не знаю какой индекс передавать, пусть будет номер перебора
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try {                
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
            }
            //регистр в Java важен, а этот метод пишется с маленькой буквы           
            //также, так как он может вернуть ошибку, тут есть обертка try/catch
        }
        //Вобще этот код вызывает у меня большие сомнения, run вызывается при запуске потока, тебе действительно нужно порождать еще потоки в каждом потоен?
    }
```

А кроме этого в `main` ты эти потоки никак не задействуешь. После ввода числа ты просто завершаешь работу, выходя из метода по команде `return`. Если тебе надо выйти из цикла, используй `break`.

С такими поправками код начнет хотя бы компилироваться, а вот работать ты его сам заставь. **И пожалуйста, не пиши в текстовом редакторе, а поставь хоть какую нибудь IDE!**

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо. Если во время работи с кодом появяться вопросы или что-то еще будет непонятно, можна к Вам обратится с вопросом (есть вероятность того, что он может оказаться глупым)?

Comment: Без проблем, мб матан я и забыл, но что такое сэссия и допуск к ней - помню ;)

Comment: Спасибо за понимание)

Comment: Метод **threadCalc()** должен высчитывать значение на каждом участке подинтегрального выражения (грубо говоря, каждый участок - это новий поток из созданого массива); **getResult()** должен после работы потоков,а значит после исполнения подсчетов на каждом участке их сложить (то есть найти значение всего интеграла).

Comment: Начав разбираться с Вашим кодом, хочу уточнить некоторые моменты. Если я понял вас правильно, то исходя из кода, при создании єкземпляра **Calcultor** создаеться массив потоков, после создания каждого потока вызываеться **threadCalc()** (1 поток -подсчет, 2  поток - подсчет...), за это отвечает **threadCalc()** который Вы поставили первой строчкойв **run()**. Я правильно все понимаю?

Comment: Второй вопрос: a нужно было подключать **logging.Level**;
**logging.Logger** без них не компилился код?

Comment: 1)При создании экземпляра, потоки не создаются, он начинаются тогда, когда ты вызываешь .start() у объекта, который в свою очередь вызывает метод .run() в отдельно потоке.

Comment: 2) эти два класса добавляются просто стандартные логеры, можеш спокойно удалить, но try/catch не трогай - не скомпилится.

Comment: а что-такое "логгеры" и "исключения". Как лучше это понять для себя, и что делает "try/catch"?

Comment: Еще я понял, что при большом кол-ве интервалов код просто не будет работать, так как будет занимать ресурсы ноута конкретно память (exeption outofmemory). Просто неправильные требования у задания. А как бы Вы реализовали код (интересно на будущее)?

Comment: Логер - история событий. Исключение - ошибка. try/catch не дает ошибке вырубить приложение, а делает что-то заместо этого и продолжает выполнение кода. Насчет дальнейшей оптимизации, надо разбиратся в самом матане. Я могу гарантировать, что там можно его оптимизировать. Да и скорее всего в принципе сток потоков плодить не надо. Но как это оптимизировать, эт уже к комунить другому. Как я уже сказал мне неохота в матан лезть.

Comment: последний вопрос: Вы говорите  "делает что-то заместо этого и продолжает выполнение кода", значит результат будет неправильным или нет?

Comment: Ошибки выполнения различных операций можно "перехватывать". Например если программа не смогла открыть файл(не нашла его), то вместо того, чтобы завершится с ошибкой, приложение может, например, вывести окно с сообщением, что файл не найден и ждать ввода нового адреса.

Comment: понял. Благодарю Вас за уделенное  мне внимание)